# .then((result) => function(result)) vs .then(function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

What's the difference between these two function calls on then in Promise?
Does .then(function) autimatically add a result parameter to function?
How does `.then((result) => function(result))` work, and how `.then(function)` works

Comment: In both cases `function` gets called with the same first parameter.  In case 1 there is an intermediate function accepting 1 parameter from the mechanism that handles `.then` and passing it to `function`.  In case 2 there is no such intermediate, the param is directly passed from `.then` to `function`.  Functionally they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for explaination, now I understand!